# jQuery: Find input fields except checkbox with a particular parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Trying this multiselect bootstrap plug in which shows options as check-box.
[image]

Problem is when I try to all the input fields, it goes all those checkboxes too. I want to avoid these option checkboxes.
That's how they look in HTML

```
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="2"> Options 2</label>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="3"> Options 3</label>
</a>
</li>
```

Current code is

```
$(section).find('input:not(:checkbox), select').each(function(i, field) {
```

How can I filter only those checkboxes which has a parent `<label class="checkbox">`?

Comment: It is more of a parent div. So the form is divided into sections and section has input fields.

Comment: Your question is still a little unclear; you're replacing the drop-down from a select with a <li> full of checkboxes? Are you attempting to isolate them in case you re-run the initialization? What exactly are you trying to accomplish and what are you trying to accomplish with your collection (the one full of selects and inputs that are not checkboxes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make your selector:

```
input:not(label.checkbox :checkbox), select
```

That will include any `<input>` element that isn't inside a `<label class="checkbox">` element and of type `checkbox`, as well as all `<select>` elements.

Your code would become:

```
$(section).find('input:not(label.checkbox :checkbox), select').each(function(i, field) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$(section).find('input:not(:checkbox), select').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parent().children('.checkbox')[0];
}).each(function(i, field) {
   //your code here 
});
```

Comment: @HimanshuYadav the above code will not select the checkbox which has a sibling element with the class name '.checkbox'.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav it is ok.. this code can be improved if you provide the relevant html code above. if you are happy with this then no issues :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( section ).find( '.checkbox' ).find( 'input:not( :checkbox ), select' ).each(

    function( i, field ) {
```